# How can I delete "NaN" fields(rows) in a ".CSV" file with python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I read a `.CSV` file with 1000 rows and 10 columns by this code:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\a.csv')
```

But it seems there is some `NaN` elemnts in the read file. So I want to write a code that finds the rows that contain `NaN` elements and completely delete those rows. For example `dataset[100][7]= 'Nan'`So it should delete the row 100 completely.

How can I do this?

Comment: Use `df = df.dropna()`

Comment: @jezrael: If one element in a row is `NaN` will this command remove the whole row or just the `NaN` element?

Comment: It remove always row, not possible remove NaN without row.